# Shell script call API via curl and process response

Tags: shell, curl, jwt

I need to create a shell script that calls my login API via curl.
The script should be able to store and process the response from curl api call.

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Extract bearer token from curl calling login api"
echo
# Check cURL command if available (required), abort if does not exists
type curl >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "Required curl but it's not installed. Aborting."; exit 1; }
echo

PAYLOAD='{"email": "dummy-user@acme.com", "password": "secret"}'

curl -s --request POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  http://acme.com/api/authentications/login --data "${PAYLOAD}"
```

My problem in the given script is:

1. it does not get the response of curl calling the API.
2. From the response json, get only the token value.

**Sample Login API response:**

```
{
  "user": {
    "id": 123,
    "token": "<GENERATED-TOKEN-HERE>",
    "email": "dummy-user@acme.com",
    "refreshToken": "<GENERATED-REFRESH-TOKEN>",
    "uuid": "1239c226-8dd7-4edf-b948-df2f75508888"
  },
  "clientId": "abc12345",
  "clientSecretKey": "thisisasecret"
}
```

I only need to get the value of `token` and store it in a variable... I will use token value in other curl api call as bearer token.

What do I need to change in my script to extract the `token` value from the response of curl api call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your curl statement has an error in it. You are executing it with the target URL as an header field:

```
curl --request POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H http://acme.com/api/authentications/login --data "${PAYLOAD}"
                                                       ^
                                                       |
                                                   Remove this header flag
```

Also the silent `-s` flag helps when curl is executed from scripts:

> -s, --silent
>   Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute.

Afterwards you could store the data in a variable and execute a regular expression on it to extract the token you need for further processing.

The complete script could look like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Extract bearer token from curl calling login api"
echo
# Check cURL command if available (required), abort if does not exists
type curl >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "Required curl but it's not installed. Aborting."; exit 1; }
echo

PAYLOAD='{"email": "dummy-user@acme.com", "password": "secret"}'

RESPONSE=`curl -s --request POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://acme.com/api/authentications/login --data "${PAYLOAD}"`

TOKEN=`echo $RESPONSE | grep -Po '"token":(\W+)?"\K[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?=")'`

echo "$TOKEN" # Use for further processsing
```

Comment: I am having problem with regular expressions, please see https://regexr.com/4eccp I cannot extract just the value of `token`.

Comment: Try the following regex instead: `"token":(\W+)?"\K[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?=")`. The online tool you provided uses JavaScript regex syntax, `grep` uses Perl regex. Try this with https://regex101.com/
In addition: **Be careful with posting JWT tokens here. It contains confidential information when pasted e.g. on https://jwt.io/**

Comment: If I hard code RESPONSE='<COPIED_RESPONSE_FROM_CURL_CALL>'... regular expression works. but if I use RESPONSE='<CURL_CALL>' it does not return anything (Token is blank).

Comment: It is really close, regexp works if I hard code the response.. but if I call curl... response looks correct... but regexp does not work.. it cannot return the token (empty/blank)

Comment: @FlorianSchlag Where does the single quote just before the double quote preceding token close? (I'm writing  a Bash script, if that's relevant)

Comment: @PakiPat the closing single quote was missing. I edited my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution to parsing JSON with regex is [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) :

```
echo '{ "user": { "id": 123, "token": "<GENERATED-TOKEN-HERE>", "email": "dummy-user@acme.com", "refreshToken": "<GENERATED-REFRESH-TOKEN>", "uuid": "1239c226-8dd7-4edf-b948-df2f75508888" }, "clientId": "abc12345", "clientSecretKey": "thisisasecret" }' | jq -r '.user.token'
```

Comment: I am afraid Installing other command is not an option (jq) on my case